# scrapy splash not getting info that works at scrapy shell

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I have a scraper that gets all info, excpet for one endpoint. It 's done with scrapy splash because this content loads with Js. when I test it via scrapy shell as follows :

```
scrapy shell 'http://localhost:8050/render.html?url="https://www.solodeportes.com.ar/zapatillas-nike-air-max-systm-gris.html?nosto=productcategory-nosto-1-fallback-nosto-1"/page-with-javascript.html&timeout=10&wait=0.5'
 
response.css('div.product-options-wrapper.swatch-attribute-options.clearfix div.swatch-option:not(.disabled)::text').getall()
```

I get info needed : ['39',
'39.5',
'40',
'41',
'41.5',
'42',
'43',
'43.5',
'44',
'44.5',
'45',
'46']

but when I try to do the same via .py I m getting empty the 'Talles' key . The script is this :

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from datetime import datetime
import os

if os.path.exists('Solodeportes.csv'):
    os.remove('Solodeportes.csv')
    print("The file has been deleted successfully")
else:
    print("The file does not exist!")


class SolodeportesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'solodeportes'
    start_urls = ['https://www.solodeportes.com.ar/marcas.html?p=0']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_URI':'Solodeportes.csv', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv', 'FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING':'utf-8',}

    def parse(self, response):
        #total_products = int(int(response.css('.toolbar-number::text').get()) / 24) + 1
        total_products = 2
        for count in range(0, total_products):
            yield SplashRequest(url=f'https://www.solodeportes.com.ar/marcas.html?p={count}',
                          callback=self.parse_listings)

    def parse_listings(self, response):
        all_listings = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"product-item-type")]/../@href').getall()
        for url in all_listings:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.detail_page, args={'wait': 5})

    def detail_page(self, response):
        yield {
            'Casa':'Solo Deportes',
            'Sku': response.css('[itemprop="sku"]::text').get(),
            'Type': response.css('div.product.attribute.modelo div.value::text').get(),
            'Name': response.css('[data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"]::text').get(),
            'Price': response.css('span.price::text').get(),
            'Link': response.url,
            'Talles': response.css('div.product-options-wrapper .swatch-attribute-options.clearfix div.swatch-option:not(.disabled)::text').getall(),
            'Date':datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            
        }


process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(SolodeportesSpider)
process.start()
```

I don t understand what's wrong with this..I tried changing the wait parameter from 0.5 to 5....but it didn't work...what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance